# How to get base uri for backend in the package?

Tags: node.js, package, angular5

I have Angular6 application, in which I installed Angular5 package (as node_module). Angular6 application is running on 8080 port. Backend is running on 3080 port. When I call service from Angular6 application (any file), backend is targeted with good base Uri (which include 3080 port). But problem is with angular5 package, in which I have interal routing, and when service is targeted from package, it's called with port 8080 (default application port). Is there a way to pass baseUri to package too, so backend is targeted with right baseUri?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the angular 5 package?

Comment: Angular 5 application packaged using ng-packagr and then installed into the Angular 6 application as module.